# Keep Checkbox State on Match Array Keys After Submit

Tags: php, arrays, checkbox

I want to keep the checkbox state checked after I submit the form. I've made this code

For show all checkbox options.

```
$arr_array = array();
foreach( explode( ',', 'red,blue,green,black' ) as $k => $v )
{
    $arr_array[] = array(
        "name" => trim($v),
        "selected" => ''
    );
}
```

And in template I created an If statement to check if value "selected=1" then checked else unchecked.

Also I created this function to check which options was checked

```
foreach( $arr_array as $key => $value ){
     $keys = array_keys($_POST['colors']);
}
```

How to keep the state of checkbox after submit the form?

Comment: You wanna reload page and see all prev states? If so, then you need to save it to DB or in [localstorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage) at least. Show your HTML part with corresponded JS.

Comment: I mean, when I submit the form but some data error, it will back to the form with last data fill.

Comment: Current page doesn't reloading during submission?

Comment: it's, for example. my user already choose the colors checkbox, but when try to submit it, his/her incorrect when filling the captcha so it will be return back with error state. And what I want is their previous checkbox checked is same as before error capthca

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the way to get this, hope someone can using this to.

you just need to add this after array()

```
foreach ($arr_array as &$arr) {
   if ($arr["name"] == $_POST) {
    $arr["selected"] = '1';
   }
}
```

Hope this helps